# What does addNotify() do?

Tags: java

Alright so I was watching a tutorial on Java game development and he used some code I am unsure of what it does. I would like to know because the game won't run without it. I am trying to learn as much on this subject as I can and would like to know what it does. The code is below thank you for all your help.

```
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    if(thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think it does?

Comment: I'm not sure that's why I'm asking. I see that it creates a thread but why is that of any importance.

Comment: What does it pass to the thread?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You post that comment on 20% of the questions I look at every day. The top Google result for *addNotify() java* says something like "If you really want to know what it does, read the source code." Among the top 10 Google results there is not one clear and well written answer to this question. Therefore, this is a good opportunity to bring people looking for an answer *here*, and grow our community. Long drawn out answers with "I think it does this... I looked here and here and here..." are not *necessarily* better. Short, concise questions *can* be effective.

Comment: That said, the title needs work, so I suggested an edit.

Comment: Thanks Rusher I think that will really help

Comment: @Rusher The OP hasn't specified where `addNotify()` comes from. As such, we can assume that it is not part of some standard API. The question is therefore equivalent to: "What does `fooBar()` do?" Without more details it is not helpful to anyone. These questions I ask in the comment are meant to push the OP to look for hints in the right place.

Comment: `Thread` is part of the standard API, specifically `java.lang.Thread`. You can look up the javadoc and find out what it does and how its methods work.  `addKeyListener` might be part of the API, it might not. Again, you'll have to look at where it comes from. After that, you combine the behaviors of each component to analyze the whole.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you honestly believe that, then you should vote to close the question as unclear. Personally, I think your assumption is rather silly, given that `addNotify()` is *clearly* [part of the standard API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addNotify%28%29). I suppose that's why your vote is yours, and my vote is mine.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JavaDocs for `Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addNotify%28%29)

> Makes this Container displayable by connecting it to a native screen
>   resource. Making a container displayable will cause all of its
>   children to be made displayable. This method is called internally by
>   the toolkit and should not be called directly by programs.

From the [JavaDocs for `JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#addNotify%28%29)

> Notifies this component that it now has a parent component. When this
>   method is invoked, the chain of parent components is set up with
>   KeyboardAction event listeners. This method is called by the toolkit
>   internally and should not be called directly by programs.

Okay, but what does that all mean?

Basically, `addNotify` in `Container` sets up the event dispatchers/monitors used internally by the components to track and handle events.  It will also call `addNotify` to all the child components it containers.

`addNotify` in `JComponent` fires a `ancestor` property change event and sets up the focus transversal and key bindings for the component.

These methods are called by `Container#addImpl` when a component is added to a displayable container (one that is attached to a native peer).  This provides them with notification that the component has been added, specifically, to a native peer.

This is a good way to know that you component is been added to a displayable context and will soon be laid out and painted.

Equally, there is also a `removeNotify` for when a component is removed or it's parent container is removed from a displayable context.

Comment: @user2892875 It's a massively useful method, don't screw with it ;)

Comment: That's what it sounds like. I will just leave it be and thanks so much for you help!